# ActionBar showAsAction not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar

After a lot of googling, I have not been able to solve this issue. I am trying to run a very simple code that just creates an ActionBar, puts a button on it and adds a listener to that button. The problem is that the first item does not appear as an Action but instead appears with the dropdown with Settings even though I have set it showAsAction="always". This is my xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
    android:title="@string/action_create_order"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_web_asset_black_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="always"></item>

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_create_order:
            Intent intent=new Intent(this, OrderActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app:showAsAction` is used with [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html). You must either extend that class and use `AppCompat` or use `android:showAsAction`.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:showAsAction="always`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
android:title="@string/action_create_order"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_web_asset_black_24dp"
android:orderInCategory="1"
android:showAsAction="always"> </item>

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
android:title="@string/action_settings"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```